# Vulnerabilities while installing ng bootstrap module

Tags: angular, npm, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

While installing `@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap` module in my `Angular 13` application , it got installed with the below message. `4 high severity vulnerabilities`. Does anyone have idea on what those vulnerabilities are and how to avoid those.

[image]

Comment: `Does anyone have idea on what those vulnerabilities are` > run  `npm audit` | 
`how to avoid those` > There's no real way to prevent them, but they can usually be fixed by running `npm audit fix`

Answer (score 0):

basically some dependencies have vulnerabilities. There is not much you can do apart from updating the dependency to the latest version or replace the dependency.

first thing you can try is: `npm audit fix`
second thing you can do is: `npm outdated`
this will give you a list of all outdated packages. Try to update them if possible and if you are lucky the vulnerabilities are fixed.

Probably someone will disagree but you should not panic for this message.
Always try to update your dependecies and use well mantained packages